# can't figure out how align 3 pictures side by side

Tags: html, css

The photos should look like this:

[image: the photos should look like this]

This is a uni assignment and it’s like my first experience with coding so please try to understand. And I'm pretty sure there are a lot of mistakes so please help me out if you can.

This is my code so far:

```css
.wrapper-home-photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #1d1d1e;
    padding: 100px;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-home-photo">
    <figure>
    <img src="./src/imgs/home-photos/strangerthings-home1.jpg" width="540" height="330" />
    </figure>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-home-photo">
    <figure>
        <img src="./src/imgs/home-photos/strangerthings-home2.png" width="400" height="220" />
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-home-photo">
    <figure>
        <img src="./src/imgs/home-photos/strangerthings-home3.jpg" width="540" height="330" />
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS has a syntax error (missing a closing bracket `}`). Also, it's not clear how three elements, all 100% width, are supposed to be side by side. Maybe think about that, and do a little research on this site; there are many questions about arranging elements side by side.

Comment: `<div></div>`s are block-level Elements, which means that they break a line and have a width and height. `<img />`s are inline-block, which mean that they do not break a line but do have a width and height. `<span></span>`s are inline, which means that they do not break a line and do not have a width or a height. inline Elements also don't respect padding or margins. If you want, you could just `.wrapper-home-photo{ display:inline-block; }`.

Comment: I regards to my previous comment, your parent Element would have to be able to fit the Elements all together with their padding side by side *(math)*, then you would do `.wrapper-home-photo{ display:inline-block; background-color: #1d1d1e; padding: 100px; }`.

Comment: thank you all so so much, I’m gonna try all this and let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

Put all the images into one centralized div with the class **block**. From here, you can use **display: grid** to align all the contents of the div into a grid. Then just do **grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;** to create 3 columns, each 1fr being 1 fraction of the div, and since you have three images you will need 3 columns. You can use **grid-gap: 20px** to add some margins and separation between each image.

```css
.banner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="https://www.muralswallpaper.com/app/uploads/Green-Tropical-Plant-Wallpaper-Mural-Plain.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.muralswallpaper.com/app/uploads/Green-Tropical-Plant-Wallpaper-Mural-Plain.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.muralswallpaper.com/app/uploads/Green-Tropical-Plant-Wallpaper-Mural-Plain.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
<div class="wrapper-home-photo">
   <figure>
    <img src="./src/imgs/home-photos/strangerthings-home1.jpg" width="540" height="330" />
   </figure>

   <figure>
    <img src="./src/imgs/home-photos/strangerthings-home2.png" width="400" height="220" />
   </figure>

   <figure>
    <img src="./src/imgs/home-photos/strangerthings-home3.jpg" width="540" height="330" />
       </figure>
</div>
```